# GitHub Action fails without information

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

One of my GitHub actions has failed with the following output:

[image: GitHub Actions UI]

There's no information here, and there doesn't seem to be any UI that I can interact with to get more information. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you enable debug logging?

Comment: All of the tests that pass have more detailed logs of various steps that they're executing, including steps that are handled by GH, and not by my code. I'm not sure exactly which debug logging you're referring to, but I doubt it would matter - I should see _something_ here.

Comment: See https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/managing-a-workflow-run#enabling-debug-logging

Comment: Did you try re-triggering the build?

Comment: @MadhuBhat Yes, I ended up pushing another version of the commit, triggering a new build. However, that doesn't answer the question of what went wrong with the original build.

Comment: Yeah @joshlf what I'm trying to say is, it might have been a failure or one-off glitch internal to Github and we might not know what caused it. The only option you have is to try to contact Github support.

Comment: @MadhuBhat understood :)